# dbprovider object for Spring in a dotnet project

Tags: .net, spring, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to create a dbprovider object for Spring in a dotnet project

```
IDbProvider dbProvider = DbProviderFactory.GetDbProvider("System.Data.SqlClient");
```

I am able to create this object for SQL Data provider but for my project the Data Provider is Postgres, and I have tried but cannot find the general provider name for postgres to be passed as a parameter. I have to pass a general provider name and not an exact version name as the version we are using for postgres is 3.2.3 and it is not supported by Dotnet Spring framework.